# DOM nodes not garbage collected

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, google-chrome-devtools

I have a question about using Chrome's developer tools to debug memory leaks in a single-page web application.

According to Google's [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-memory-profiling#memory-profiling-faq), after taking a heap snapshot you'll see red and yellow detached DOM nodes. The yellow nodes are those still being reference by JavaScript, and effectively represent the *cause* of the leak. The red nodes are not directly referenced in JavaScript, but they're still "alive"—likely because they're part of a yellow node's DOM tree.

I've been able to fix several memory leaks by drilling down on all the yellow nodes in my heap snapshots and finding where in our code there was still a reference to them. However, now I've got a situation I'm not sure how to handle: Only red nodes are showing up in my heap snapshot!

If there is no JavaScript reference to these nodes, what are some other reasons that they wouldn't be garbage collected? Also, why does it say there are 155 entries but only show 60? I'm wondering if Chrome simply isn't showing one or more yellow nodes:

[image: No references in JavaScript, but still not garbage collected?]

Comment: Do you ever use `eval()` in your code?

Comment: Have you looked at more details on any of these DOM elements to see which DOM elements they are and perhaps that gives you a clue as to what code would have ever referenced them.  One source of references that trips some people up is closures that you are done with, but are still alive for some reason.

Comment: After a quick search of the project I discovered that several third-party libraries we're using (require.js, history.js, pubnub.js) do make `eval()` calls. For now I'll assume that the problem is not with these libraries, but why do you ask about `eval()` in this context?

Comment: I was thinking it could create a closure leak because when you have an `eval` call in a function that is kept around permanently (say like an event handler), the JS engine isn't going to be able to clean up the variables that the handler closed over because it can't know if the eval'd string is going to reference one of them. But now that I think about it, that would still require a variable reference... so I'm not so sure.

Comment: @jfriend00 I think you might be on to something, but I've exhausted every related closure I can find and the problem persists. I'm still wondering why Chrome says there are 155 entries but only shows me 60. For other large DOM trees, there's always a button at the bottom that says "Show 100 More" (or something similar).

Comment: @jfriend00: You were right. After drilling in on the DOM elements, I was able to track this down to an element being referenced in a closure. If you add your comment as an answer, I'll mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your request, adding this as an asnwer.  Have you looked at more details on any of these DOM elements to see which DOM elements they are and perhaps that gives you a clue as to what code would have ever referenced them. One source of references that trips some people up is closures that you are done with, but are still alive for some reason.